# Can we calculate derivatives in terms of matrix-by-matrix?

Tags: calculus, matrices

Calculate the gradient of $W2$ given $$hW2+b2$$ The given solution is $h^T$.

Could anyone explain how we get such a solution? In my knowledge, it's impossible to have gradient of a matrix given a function which is also a matrix.

Note $h \in \mathbb{R}^{20 \times 5}, W2 \in \mathbb{R}^{5 \times 10}, b2 \in \mathbb{R}^{20 \times 10}$ are all variables, and $h, b2$ are independent of $W2$.

Answer (score 1):

In index notation
$$\eqalign{
 Y_{ij} &= H_{ik}\,W_{kj} + B_{ij} \cr\cr
 dY_{ij} &= H_{ik}\,dW_{kj} \cr\cr
\frac{\partial Y_{ij}}{\partial W_{ps}}&=H_{ik}\,\delta_{kp}\,\delta_{js} \,\,= H_{ip}\,\delta_{js} \cr\cr
}$$
In matrix notation
$$\eqalign{
 Y &= HW + B \cr\cr
dY &= H\,dW \cr
\operatorname{vec}(dY) &= \operatorname{vec}(H\,dW\,I) \cr
dy &= (I\otimes H)\,dw \cr\cr
\frac{\partial y}{\partial w} &= I\otimes H \cr
}$$